# Displaying an image from mysql database using php

Tags: php

I'm trying to display an image in my mysql database at a set size... The following code is giving me a blank image error. Any ideas? I'm new to php so its probably something stupid I've missed. I've been messing around with "'"'"''""' marks as thats what I'm thinking it is... but i can't get it.

```
 <?php echo "<img src'=/images/blogimages/' .$image. width="100" height="100"'>;" ?>
```

I can do it without the width and height tags. but its doesn't work when i include the,

Comment: Check your image `src` path and also check for console if you are getting any `404 Not Found` also change the code to : `src='/images/blogimages/$image'`

Comment: Do you not mean `src='/images/blogimages/$image' width='100'...`? I.e. Yes, your quotes are all dodgy.

Comment: Use this Instead to pre check the availability of Image in the source path to avoid this like blank errors.   

    `<img width="100" height="100" 
    <?php if(file_exists("images/blogimages/$image"))
    {
      echo "src=images/blogimages/$image";
    }   
    else 
    {
      echo "Image Not Found.";
    }
    ?>
    />`